# Permission denied when pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have 2 SSH key on my laptop:

- `rsa_id_1`
- `rsa_id_2`

and another SSH key on my desktop on my office:

- `rsa_id_3`

My project was uploaded in GitHub using my desktop in my office. Now I want to work on it using my laptop. I added `rsa_id_2` as SSH key on GitHub so there are 2 SSH key there: `rsa_id_2` and `rsa_id_3` .

I was able to clone the project on my laptop, but when I push my changes, I get an error stating that permission was denied.

Was it because I have `rsa_id_1` on my laptop? And it is the one being read when I push my changes? I can't add `rsa_id_1` as SSH key on GitHub as it is being used by another account in GitHub.

Or is there another step that I need to do to be able to push my changes using my laptop (eg. configure git, and etc.)

Comment: [Trouble shooting steps here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection) it’s usually  helpful to add the `-v` option for more output.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `~/.ssh/config` file and add the following lines:

```
Host github.com
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_id_2
```

Also, please refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use/912281#912281) superuser question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

simply this is the way to interact with ssh key.
 in git bash tool, type below code

```
 $ keygen
```

Then bash displaying a URL, copy that URL  and type below

```
$cat <add the URL here>
```

then you can see  very long URL, copy that URL go to GitHub setting and click "ssh and GPG keys"
From there paste that key, finally, come to your git bash and type below

```
$ssh -T git@github.com
```

this last code, ssh authentication happen